# Java else if with strings not working - Scanner(System.in);

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I am very new in java and to programming overall. Recently, I have started an IA mock-up program, but my `else-if` part of code is not showing in the terminal, I suppose. However, the `if` and the `else` statements do seem to work perfectly.
I'd appreciate any help you can provide.
Sorry for my lackluster English and my inaccurate words.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class IA
{
    public static void main(String []args){

       Scanner lector= new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("Di algo");
       String input = lector.next();    

       if (input.equals ("Hola") || input.equals("hola") || input.equals("ola")){
            System.out.println("Hola, humano");
       }else if (input==("quien eres")){
            System.out.println("Una pobre ilusión de inteligencia artificial");
       }else{
        System.out.println("Adiós");
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Code should be in the question, not an image

Comment: Write the code here, properly formatted. Translate to English to the best of your ability. (By "here" I mean "edit your question", not add as a comment).

Comment: Define 'not working'. Is there an error message or is the output not what you expected?

Comment: check your input string. next() does not consider strings after spaces. And `most imporatntly don't attach image, write code.`

Comment: I'll give you a stab-in-the-dark hint: use `nextLine()` instead of `next()` because `quien heres` are two tokens as far as `next` is concerned.

Comment: Firstly, there shouldn't be spaces between the function and its parameters, but thats more stylistic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is not checking the input value. First check the input value...:

```
System.out.println(input);
```

...and see if the value is ok. Then you can say if your "`if-else`" component is working or not.

Also delete the gap @ `input.equals ("Hola")`. it must be `input.equals("Hola")`

Addition: You cannot use `==` operator for Strings in Java. You can use `var.equals("something")` to check if variable `var` equals to `"something"`.

Addition 2: You must use `scanner.nextLine()` to get typed string completely instead of using `scanner.next()` because `next()` gets the next WORD.

And here is [your working code](http://ideone.com/yitvbO):

Comment: A method invocation works just as well with or without a space before the brackets. It *should* be `input.equals("Hola")` according to most style guides, but "must" implies that it won't work otherwise.

Comment: Thank you very much @jsheeran you are right but here, I am trying to solve the problem and it is not as you say, it is "DEPENDS ON THE COMPILER" ;)

Comment: and where should I add that line of code? sorry

Comment: As you see in this link: http://ideone.com/yitvbO you must add it just before your if-else structure. Could you please mark as the right answer?

Comment: I changed the code as you asked, but the issue still persists. I get "Adiós" displayed.

Comment: But are the values correct? Because I copied and pasted your code and given the input as "Hola" and worked great. You can see code, input and output in the link I provided for you: http://ideone.com/yitvbO

Comment: Check the stdin and stdout in the bottom of the page under the code.

Comment: the if else component is not working. It goes directly to the else compoment

Comment: hola works, but quien eres doesn't

Comment: this is ignored

Comment: else if (input==("quien eres")){
                System.out.println("Una pobre ilusión de inteligencia artificial");
           }

Comment: So I think you won't see the "quien eres" in the System.out.println(input). You must see first "quien" and later "eres" in the values which are not suitable for the if-else code part because scanner.next() only gets the next WORD. To provide it, you must use scanner.nextLine();. Try it, you will see it will work.

Comment: And also, you must use input.equals("quien eres"). Because operator == is not working for Strings in Java.

Comment: Check this is working now http://ideone.com/yitvbO

Comment: Thanks. It works. Apologies for my ineptutude.

Comment: No problem, you know nobody is a master and everybody understands in a different way as Einstein indicated years ago and people still do not understand :) Cheers!

Comment: Hey, quick question. How can I make it so that my program can recieve more messages wihtout ending? Like a chatbot.

Comment: Quick answer: "No quick questions" ;)

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to change the delimiter of the Scanner if you want it to pick up tokens that contain spaces. Because the default delimiter is a space, if it encounters `quien eres`, `next()` will be `quien`.